# Every LL Grammar is not ambigious

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

An LL grammar is a formal grammar that can be parsed by an LL parser, which parses the input from Left to right, and constructs a Leftmost derivation of the sentence (hence LL, compared with LR parser that constructs a rightmost derivation).

Q : Prove that every LL grammar is not ambigious.

Note : I know how to show that a grammar is ambigious ( i should find two production sequence that lead to 1 string ) but i don't know how to show some grammar is not ambigious !!!

Comment: **Exactly** what is the statement of the problem?  "Prove that every LL grammar is not ambiguous" means "prove that NO LL grammar is ambiguous".   "Prove that not every LL grammar is ambiguous" would be "some grammar s not ambiguous".